# Servlet pass data to jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, request

I have a servlet that do all the backend fetching and pass the data to render a jsp.

```
request.setAttribute("name", "ASDADAS");
request.getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

and inside my home.jsp, i called the value

`<%= request.getAttribute("name")%>`

but i keep getting the error below

```
java.io.IOException: Error - getOutputStream() called on a request that has already returned a Writer - enable debug logging on com.isomorphic.servlet.ProxyHttpServletResponse to see a stack trace of the previous caller.
```

Comment: the error message seems pretty much on point.. what is your question specifically?

Comment: Is this all the code in the servlet method as your code would normally not cause an issue? Try getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/home.jsp").forward(request, response)

Comment: Did you already produce any output in that Servlet? You should be doing that in the JSP instead.

Comment: can you post your whole servlet class ?

Comment: @giorgiga my question is that my servlet cannot forward to jsp. after some research, i think the issue casued by my framework as my framwork has their own writter.

Comment: @GerbenJongerius i tried with this method too but it failed.

Comment: @Thilo my idea is that i will put all my logic in servlet site that pass the fetched data to construct the jsp. If I do all my logic in jsp then it will be vulnerable for attackers, At least inside servlet i can provide the minimum security

Comment: @AvijitBarua my servlet is just a typical servlet that contains logic that process doGet and doPost.  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  this.processRequest(request, response);
 }

Comment: According to the error, it has been said that request has been already used, that why I told you to post whole servlet.

Comment: Keeping logic in the servlet makes sense for design reasons, but there is no difference security-wise. A JSP gets compiled into a servlet as well, it just provides an alternative syntax more geared toward creating HTML output. Any vulnerabilities in your logic would affect both JSP and servlet equally.

Comment: @AvijitBarua thank you very much for your help, I found the conflict between my existing framework and my code. both using getOutputStream at the same time, now i need to research on how to bypass compression filter

Comment: @Thilo thank you for your reply, I assumed that business logic should have kept more in servlet site instead of jsp to improve security wise but apparently I am wrong on this. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

better way to use

response.sendRedirect("/home.jsp");

it will works fine

Comment: How is the request attribute set on the previous line supposed to survive that?

Comment: i tried with sendRedirect but the issue with redirect is that it wont pass any attributes that i set. I needed the data fetch from servlet in order to construct the jsp.

Answer (score 0):

better way to use

response.sendRedirect("/home.jsp");

it will works fine

```
//System.out.println("username"+request.getParameter("username")+"password"+request.getParameter("password"));
    request.setAttribute("username", request.getParameter("username"));
    RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("home.jsp");
    rd.forward(request, response);
```